# Input type=file can not accept large size images

Tags: php, html

I want to upload any size of image using input type="file". I am currently trying to upload 2-3 MB images but it doesn't work and other form data also doesn't show up in the database.

I am currently using this code in my form for image upload:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 upload2">
    <img id="file1" width="150" height="80">
    <input type="file" name="a_image[]" required id="imgupload" style="display:none" onChange="document.getElementById('file1').src = window.URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0])">
    <br>
    <a href="#" class="upload" onclick="$('#imgupload').trigger('click'); return false;"> <i class="fa fa-upload" aria-hidden="true"></i> Upload </a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 upload2">
    <img id="file2" width="150" height="80">
    <input type="file" name="a_image[]" id="imgupload1" style="display:none" onChange="document.getElementById('file2').src = window.URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0])">
    <br>
    <a href="#" class="upload" onclick="$('#imgupload1').trigger('click'); return false;"><i class="fa fa-upload" aria-hidden="true"></i> Upload </a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 upload2">
    <img id="file3" width="150" height="80">
    <input type="file" name="a_image[]" id="imgupload2" style="display:none" onChange="document.getElementById('file3').src = window.URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0])">
    <br>
    <a href="#" class="upload" onclick="$('#imgupload2').trigger('click'); return false;"><i class="fa fa-upload" aria-hidden="true"></i> Upload </a>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 upload2">
    <img id="file4" width="150" height="80">
    <input type="file" name="a_image[]" id="imgupload3" style="display:none" onChange="document.getElementById('file4').src = window.URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0])">
    <br>
    <a href="#" class="upload" onclick="$('#imgupload3').trigger('click'); return false;"><i class="fa fa-upload" aria-hidden="true"></i> Upload </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

on model page

```
$id = $a_id;
    $i = 0;
    foreach($_FILES['a_image']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name)
    {
        $i++;
        $file_tmp =$_FILES['a_image']['tmp_name'][$key];
        move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"template/uploads/product/ad_".$id."_".$i.'.jpg');
        $source_path = "template/uploads/product/ad_".$id."_".$i.".jpg";
        $thumb_path = 'template/uploads/product/thumb/ad_'.$id.'_'.$i.'.jpg';
        $this->upload_thumbnail($source_path,$thumb_path,'200','200');
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the default max size for input type file is, **20 megabytes**.

To change this...

Add the below code to your `.htaccess` if creating a `php.ini` with similar values.

```
 php_value post_max_size 100M
 php_value upload_max_filesize 100M
 php_value memory_limit 64M
```

It may not work, but try it out anyway!

Comment: `upload_max_filesize = 4M` `post_max_size = 8M`  this solution is also working

Answer (score 0):

limit these in php.ini by setting the following:

```
`upload_max_filesize = 4M` `post_max_size = 8M`
```